# How can one make dead keys globally functional on a gnomeless Ubuntu environment?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, keyboard-layout, dead-keys

Since I removed gnome and started using a WM only setup (bspwm) apps like **st, urxvt, emacs** and even **alacritt**y stoped smart managing dead keys. **Chrome, brave, firefox** and **gnome-terminal** still do though, why is that?

By smart managing, I mean when you hit tilde `~` and then `a` you get `ã`, but if you double hit tilde, you get it alone `~`

st and alikes just won't work with dead keys. Won't render `ã õ á ó ú í` and even `~ ´ ^` . I have to switch the kb layout in order to have at least tilde alone (~) which is very tedious:

```
setxkbmap -model abnt2 -layout br -option caps:escape -variant nodeadkeys
```

In my archlinux system everything works fine by default, no extra setup required and I'm using no DE in there also, only dwm as wm

I have tried so many methods for the past 5 months that I can't even recall. 
Some enlightment would be greatly apreciated.

What's responsible for system-wide dead-key management on Ubuntu?

EDIT:

output of `cat /etc/default/keyboard`

```
XKBLAYOUT="br"
BACKSPACE="guess"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBMODEL="abnt2"
XKBOPTIONS="caps:escape,compose:ralt,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
```

Comment: sure, going to edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all this time it was Gunnar's suggestion in the comments that solved the issue:creating another user.

there must have been some config file that was messing with some of the terminals mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Enabling the *Portuguese (Brazil)* keyboard layout, I can do for instance:

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> followed by <kbd>A</kbd> to type ä

And I can do

<kbd>dead_tilde</kbd> (to the right of <kbd>Ç</kbd>) followed by <kbd>A</kbd> to type ã

or

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>dead_tilde</kbd> followed by <kbd>A</kbd> to type â

So the most common use of dead keys seems to work fine with the *Portuguese (Brazil)* layout.

One observation, though, is that you have defined <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> as your compose key. That way you can't use that key to access 3:rd and 4:th level symbols which are built-in in your keyboard layout. You may want to consider to disable the compose key or define some other key as the compose key.

Comment: yeah, thats the expected behavior, and it only works on chrome, firefox and gnome-terminal. st, urxvt and alacritty won't respond to dead keys.

Comment: @LeoZerino: I would suggest an experiment: Create a new user, log in as that user, and find out if the issue is still present.

Comment: after what fixed the issue was creating another user.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you append the following command to your .bashrc

`setxkbmap -model abnt2 -layout br -variant abnt2`

(change to the language of your liking, but abnt2 seems to be what you're looking for)

It does demand that you start the terminal, but that's somewhat common (apt updates and whatnot)

I've read that it is possible to configure this command on Session and Startup, but it didn't work for me. In fact, logoffs also reset my keyboard, but the terminal fixes it for me just fine.

I'm running Ubuntu 21 Mint Xfce, btw.